# How do I pass the id parameter to navigate to the details component?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios

I am trying to navigate to ProductDetailsScreen.js and see the details of a unique product, and currently I am using the parameter id in the render method to go to the unique product, but unfortunately I am getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly or if anyone have the proper way to do that I will appreciate. Here below what I am trying to do:

**AppNavigator.js:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductsScreen from "../screens/ProductsScreen";
import ProductDetailsScreen from "../screens/ProductDetailsScreen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Products" component={ProductsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={ProductDetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainStackNavigator;
```

**productDetailScreen.js:**

```
function ProductDetailsScreen(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const id = props.match.params.id;
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/id=${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data.response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addItemToCart = (item) =>
    dispatch({ type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: item });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.shoppingCartContainer}>
        <View style={styles.shoppingCart}>
          <ShoppingCartIcon />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={products}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => Separator()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={styles.productItemContainer}>
              <Image
                source={require(`../../assets/images/${index + 1}.jpg`)}
                style={styles.thumbnail}
              />

              <View style={styles.productItemMetaContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.row} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {item.id}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.categories}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.genders}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.brands}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>$ {item.price}</Text>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => addItemToCart(item)}
                    style={styles.button}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add to Cart +</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**ProductsScreen.js:**

```
function ProductsScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/product/')
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data.response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const addItemToCart = (item) =>
    dispatch({ type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: item });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.shoppingCartContainer}>
        <View style={styles.shoppingCart}>
          <ShoppingCartIcon />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={products}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => Separator()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={styles.productItemContainer}>
              <Image
                source={require(`../../assets/images/${index + 11}.jpg`)}
                style={styles.thumbnail}
              />

              <View style={styles.productItemMetaContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push("Details")}>
                  <Text style={styles.row} numberOfLines={1}>
                    {item.id}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.categories}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.genders}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.row}> {item.brands}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>$ {item.price}</Text>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => addItemToCart(item)}
                    style={styles.button}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add to Cart +</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: How are you navigating? and can we see your stack ?

Comment: Hi @Guruparan Giritharan , thanks for your reply I have just updated my post and you can have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the navigate function like below

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details",{id:1})}>
```

You can also do

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push("Details",{id:1})}>
```

The difference is push will add new screens and navigate will go back if the screen is already in the stack.

Comment: it still complaining the error in this line: const id = props.match.params.id; , maybe be I shall do something more there.

Comment: It should be props.route.params.id

Comment: Yes thanks it's worked. But one more problem is that I have put the params's value equal to 1 and of course any items I click on it navigates to the item with the value equal to 1. I want when I click on any item to navigate to that one, any advice on how I can change the value of id? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to pass the parameters use `navigation.navigate("SCREEN_NAME", {YOUR_PARAM: "PARAM_VALUE"})`

and to receive parameter on other screen use `this.props.route.params.YOUR_PARAM`

Comment: thanks it's worked. But one more problem is that I have put the params's value equal to 1 and of course any items I click on it navigates to the item with the value equal to 1. I want when I click on any item to navigate to that one, any advice on how I can change the value of id? Thanks

Comment: @saygas am sorry I didn't understand your exact problem, but as much I can understand navigation will only navigate you to the screen that you have mentioned in `navigation.navigate('screen_name')'

Comment: The problem is that I have assign 1 as the value of the parameter(navigation.navigate("Details", {id: 1})) and I have 15 products. In this case when click even on another product number except 1 I navigate again to a product number 1. What I need it is the product number I click on I should be navigate to that product. I don't if explain it well this time.

Comment: It doesn't matters what you are passing in parameters it will redirect you to the screen which you mentioned in it, here you mentioned "Details" screen so it will redirect you to the Detail screen whatever you pass in parameter(1 or 2 or 3)